Create / Erase (drop) database on Android with Delphi 11.x - 12.x at runtime
I am rewriting an old application for Android and, as new feature, I need to add a little database with just one table.
I have no problem creating the DB and table but I have a lot of problems erasing the the DB.
Due the fact that I do not know where I made a mistake, I am posting the full test code.
Main form:
unit Form_Main;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls, MobilePermissions.Model.Signature,
  MobilePermissions.Model.Dangerous, MobilePermissions.Model.Standard,
  MobilePermissions.Component;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    MP1: TMobilePermissions;
    Button1: TButton;
    btn2: TButton;
    btn1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btn2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
  Module_DataBase;

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Close;
end;

procedure TForm1.btn2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  EraseDB;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CreaDb;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MP1.Apply; // Apply the permissions
end;

end


Module
unit Module_DataBase;

interface

uses System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  System.IOUtils,
  FireDAC.Stan.Intf, FireDAC.Stan.Option,
  FireDAC.Stan.Error, FireDAC.UI.Intf, FireDAC.Phys.Intf, FireDAC.Stan.Def,
  FireDAC.Stan.Pool, FireDAC.Stan.Async, FireDAC.Phys, FireDAC.FMXUI.Wait,
  Data.DB, FireDAC.Comp.Client, FireDAC.Stan.Param, FireDAC.DatS,
  FireDAC.DApt.Intf, FireDAC.DApt, FireDAC.Comp.DataSet, FireDAC.Phys.IB,
  FireDAC.Phys.IBDef, FireDAC.Phys.SQLite, FireDAC.Phys.SQLiteDef,
  FireDAC.Stan.ExprFuncs, FireDAC.Phys.SQLiteWrapper.Stat;

type
  TDM = class(TDataModule)
    Con1: TFDConnection;
    FQR1: TFDQuery;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  DM: TDM;

  DBPath : string;

procedure CreaDB;
Procedure EraseDB;

implementation

{%CLASSGROUP 'FMX.Controls.TControl'}

{$R *.dfm}

procedure CreaDB;
var Tables : TStringList;
    SqlStr : string;
    MS     : TMemoryStream;
    I      : Integer;

begin

  DBPath := TPath.GetDocumentsPath+PathDelim +'interbase' + PathDelim + 'TestDB.ib';

  DM.Con1.Params.Values['Database'] := DBPath;

  DM.Con1.Params.Values['CreateDatabase'] := BoolToStr(not FileExists(DBPath),True);

  DM.Con1.Open;

  Tables := TStringList.Create;

  DM.Con1.GetTableNames('','','',Tables); // Get Tables

  // Check for Test table ...

  if Tables.Count=0 then
  begin
    SqlStr:='CREATE TABLE TabellaTest (';
    SqlStr:=SqlStr + 'Id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,';
    SqlStr:=SqlStr + 'Articolo CHAR(40),';
    SqlStr:=SqlStr + 'Prezzo FLOAT(2)';
    SqlStr:=SqlStr + ')';
    DM.FQR1.SQL.Clear;
    DM.FQR1.SQL.Add(SqlStr);
    DM.FQR1.ExecSQL;
    DM.Con1.GetTableNames('','','',Tables);
  end
  else
  begin
    // Just to check the tablename
    For I:=0 To Tables.Count - 1 do
        SqlStr:=Tables[i];
  end;
  FreeAndNil(Tables);
end;

procedure EraseDB;
begin
  if not FileExists(DBPath) then
     Exit;
  DM.Con1.Connected:=False;
  DM.FQR1.SQL.Clear;
  //DM.FQR1.SQL.Add('DROP SCHEMA ' + DBPath);       // * 1
  DM.FQR1.SQL.Add('DROP DATABASE ' + 'TestDB.ib');  // * 2
  DM.FQR1.ExecSQL;
end;

end.


Con1.DriverName := IB

TMobilepermission
You can install it via the Delphi IDE GetIt or at
https://github.com/adrianosantostreina/MobilePermissions
and permissions are: ReadingExternalStorage, WriteExternalStorage.
If I try to drop the DB I get these errors (random if I uncomment line *1 or *2) :
Error 1:

Project DB_TEST.apk raised exception class EIBNativeException with message '[FireDAC][Phys][IB]Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 1, char 6
DATABASE'.

Error 2:
I can't reproduce anymore this error but is always an EIBNativeException: "TestDB.ib" exists.
Same behavior on both Delphi version 11.3 and 12.2
What am I doing wrong?

On which line of code does the program error?

Also, why are you setting your properties in code instead of in a FDConnection?

I've removed your PS, as it is off-topic to ask us to find or recommend tools, software libraries, or other off-site resources. Please refer to the [help/on-topic] for more information.

@Error in code, the line where i get the error is DM.FQR1.ExecSQL just after the lines marked *1 and *2; Also, i set the connection properties at runtime because under android i'm not able (i don't know how to do it) to set the FDConnection in design time when the db is in a mobile device.
